# Changing state from a component doesn't change text data in tabnavigator of app js

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app where I am changing the language of the app by changing toggle state value from settings component. Every other components language is changing just fine. But the problem is in `App.js` where i'm using tab navigator and I want to change the language of the tabbar label as well. Here's how i'm trying to do so:

```js
class customDrawerContentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: 0
    }
    this.changeLang()
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.changeLang()
  }
  async changeLang() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('toggle')
      this.setState({ toggle: JSON.parse(value) })
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Text>Home Page</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const DashboardDrawerNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Single: {
    screen: Single,
    navigationOptions: {

    // Here's need to do some change i guess

      tabBarLabel: (this.state.toggle) === 0 ? "Magnum" : (this.state.toggle) === 1 ? "萬能" : "Magnum",
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=> (
        <Icon name='square-outline' color={tintColor} size={25}/>
      )
    }
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=> (
        <Icon name='settings' color={tintColor} size={25}/>
      )
    }
  }
}, {
    unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      initialRouteName: 'Toolbox',
    },
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: customDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoure: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    drawerWidth: 320,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#fff',
      inactiveTintColor: '#3F51B5',
      activeBackgroundColor: '#3F51B5',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        marginHorizontal: 10
      },
      itemStyle: {
        height: 40,
        border: 60
      },
      activeLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'normal'
      },
      inactiveLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'normal'
      }
    }
  });

const DashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: Splash,
  DashboardTabNavigator: {
    screen: DashboardDrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
  Toolbox: {
    screen: Toolbox,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
  LuckySpin:{
    screen: LuckySpin,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  }
})


const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  App: {
    screen: DashboardStackNavigator
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

This throws the error: `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.toggle')`.Following the same way in other components works fine. How can I do the same here?

Answer (score -1):

Your navigator is not a React component so `this.state` is undefined.

You should use a react-navigation route parameter instead to pass values from your React component to your navigator.

React-navigation provides [good examples](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) of how to use it.